# Memory Pressure in SQL Server - Enable LPIM or not?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, memory, performance, performance-tuning

I have slow query execution in my SQL Server 2016.

Server configurations:

1. Total Physical Memory : 128 GB
2. SQL server Max Memory : 102 GB
3. Transaction replication is enabled.
4. Database Size:1.6 TB
5. Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2) (KB4052908) - 13.0.5026.0 (X64)   Mar 18 2018 09:11:49   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Standard 10.0  (Build 14393: )

I ran the `ring buffer` query to check if Physical memory is low. The reason I checked for ring buffer for memory pressure is because my plan cache is also getting cleared frequently even though no one is running any script to clear cache.I get the below result where I see HIGH and LOW with same values for `Avail Phys Mem.KB`.

One thing I learned is for all `RESOURCE_MEMPHYSICAL_LOW` the indicator process is 2, which means memory issue is in the memory allocated to SQL Server not the rest of memory available for OS and other application.
FYI. This is a SQL Server dedicated server.

[image]

I also checked in Performance Monitor for `Avaialable MBytes` which shows the value 16,662.00 (16 GB) as below.

I think 16 GB is enough for OS+other applications, this being a SQL server dedicated server.

[image]

Checked the server diagnostics as well. It says that 25 GB is available.

[image]

So now I am confused whether:

1. Is there a memory pressure in this server?
2. The `RESOURCE_MEMPHYSICAL_LOW` flag is being set by the OS or external process or SQL Server?
3. Should I enable LPIM to fix this issue?

Additional details as per @Shanky's answer.

1. I had Query store enabled, but I disabled it a week ago.
2. rounds_count for SQL Server Plans with clock hand `HAND_EXTERNAL` is increasing.

More Details.

- I am facing huge memory grant by some queries and this is causing RESOURCE_SEMAPHORE waits for other queries.

Does this huge memory grant(one query i checked ,memory grant is ~7GB)  result in a memory pressure from SQL server and can this be the cause of plan cache clearing and `RESOURCE_MEMPHYSICAL_LOW` flag.

Comment: Pretty much any time you are asking yourself if you should enable LPIM, you should enable LPIM. Make sure this server is not responsible for running other services or applications and just do it. With 16 GB reserved for the OS, there's just no reason to make it easy for SQL Server to surrender memory. Especially when your data is 10X physical memory - it's never going to fit into memory anyway, but don't add pain.

Comment: Are you saying not to enable LPIM ?I got confused at the last line but don't add pain. –  @AaronBertrand

Comment: By "adding pain" I mean letting SQL Server giving up memory, making the problem even worse. Enable the thing.

Comment: You did not posted most important thing what is output of `select @@version`

Comment: @Shanky added that information.

Comment: There is quite some debate over this since you are running a recent windows version: https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/great-sql-server-debates-lock-pages-in-memory/

Comment: yeah.I read that article.I even reduced the SQL Max Memory to 96 GB to give more memory to OS and other process.Still `RESOURCE_MEMPHYSICAL_LOW` flag is set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is there a memory pressure in this server.

With the limited information, I cannot tell with surety. Need more parameters and output from perfmon to tell about memory pressure. But yes, from the query output you posted for the time `2018-10-23 11:22:30:457` there was indeed low memory for some process(s), not the SQL Server system as whole.

> the RESOURCE_MEMPHYSICAL_LOW flag is being set by the OS or external process or SQL server.?

Look at the output it says `RESOURCE_MEMPHYSICAL_LOW` has values of `2` from `IndicatorProcess` which means certain processe(s) which were running were indeed facing memory pressure, if `IndicatorSystem` would have had value of 2 it would have been system wide memory pressure. Also note the memory pressure is coming from low physical(RAM) not low virtual memory(VAS). So you can see just taking a value for one piece of time it is difficult to say there is *continuous* memory pressure. I suggest you read [Using sys.dm_os_ring_buffers To Diagnose Memory Issues in SQL Server](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mvpawardprogram/2012/06/04/using-sys-dm_os_ring_buffers-to-diagnose-memory-issues-in-sql-server/) to understand what the values Indicatorsystem and IndicatorProcess means

> should i enable LPIM to fix this issue.?

LPIM is *not* going to fix the issue it is only going to *mask* the issue and would come as workaround. You need to find what is causing resource monitor to flag low memory notification, it could be possible that some process running is causing it. Now plan cache getting frequently cleared is something lot of people have reported from SQL Server 2016 onward and it *may* be due to query store, are you using one ?. Query store used to be culprit behind plan cache clearing but since you are on latest SP I doubt this factor.

For seeing memory pressure for cache we can also use DMV [sys.dm_os_memory_cache_clock_hands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-os-memory-cache-clock-hands-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

```
SELECT  *
FROM sys.dm_os_memory_cache_clock_hands
WHERE rounds_count > 0
```

If `rounds_count` is increasing this means there was pressure which forced clocks to sweep the cache *more* frequently and remove the entries.

EDIT:

> I am facing huge memory grant by some queries and this is causing RESOURCE_SEMAPHORE waits for other queries.Does this huge memory grant(one query i checked ,memory grant is ~7GB) result in a memory pressure from SQL server and can this be the cause of plan cache clearing and RESOURCE_MEMPHYSICAL_LOW flag.

Yes quite likely, I have seen you raised [specific thread](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/220938/huge-memory-grant-resulting-in-resource-semaphore-waits-for-other-queries) for this question and I would only add that before you go for anything make sure you have stats updated and indexes defragmented. An outdated stats may lead to bad plan which can end up asking more memory and hence semaphore waits.

Below are list of threads talking about similar issue

- [Stackexchange thread about plan cache getting cleared frequently.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/182227/sql-server-clears-plan-cache-and-execution-stats-periodically)
- [MSDN thread about plan cache getting cleared.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2fc45a39-e33b-4741-9ead-c5e6debe1103/sql-2016-plan-cache-cleared-frequently?forum=sqldatabaseengine)

Comment: I updated more details as per your answer.Please go through it.

Comment: Hi is the rounds_count increasing only for external hands or for internal hands only and I believe the value for `removed_all_rounds_count` should also be increasing ?

Comment: yes only happening for external hands and the value is increasing for `removed_all_rounds_counts` also for external hands.

Comment: since i have `IndicatorProcess` as 2 it means certain process is facing memory pressure like you mentioned.So there is a possibility that this process can be SQL server right?Because now i noticed a blocking operation at 13:14 and at the same time i see in `RESOURCE_MEMPHYSICAL_LOW` flag set.

Comment: `IndicatorProcess`=2 means SQL Server internally detected memory pressure and signaled low physical memory. This may mean physical memory pressure. if you keep seeing this every time you run the query its quite likely you have memory pressure and this definitely may be clearing caches. LPIM may only prevent excessive trimming. You need to add more RAM or find process which is doing. If this happens all the time then you have memory pressure and adding RAM is what you should do